# Can a non-compact contractible bounded submanifold of the Euclidean space be extended to a compact submanifold?

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M$ be a non-compact contractible bounded submanifold of the Euclidean space. Is it possible to find a compact submanifold $S$ of the Euclidean space such that $M$ is a submanifold of $S$?

As a positive example, let $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x,y) \in S^1, x>0, y>0\}$ be the portion of the 1-sphere $S^1$ lying in the positive orthant of $R^2$, and $S = S^1$.

**Edit**: the following example is wrong, as pointed out by a counter-example in a comment.

More generally, let $M$ be the image of an embedding $\gamma: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\gamma(0) \neq \gamma(1)$, assuming $M$ be bounded. Then, roughly speaking, $S$ can be obtained built joining the endpoints of $M$ by a "well-behaved" smooth curve $\gamma'$ that does not intersect $M$.

I posted a [similar version of this question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467123/construct-compact-submanifold-containing-non-compact-nash-embedded-submanifold), and I was redirected here.

Comment: Hint: Consider the spiral $e^{-t}(\sin(t), \cos(t))$, $t>0$. What can you say about its length? Can it be a subset of a compact smooth planar curve?

Comment: @Moishe That curve has finite length. But multiply by $1/(t+1)$ instead.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Per their comments, OP appears to be interested in metrics of finite diameter on $M$.

Comment: @Moishe Oh, sorry. I completely missed your point. But, in fairness, I don't see why his description constrains $M$ to have finite diameter. Oh, you mean the comment to John's response. I think OP needs to revise his post significantly.

Comment: @TedShifrin: agree....

Comment: Thanks. I will accept John's post, which does answer the original question, and reformulate my question more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the answer is "no" in general.

Suppose that $M$ is the interior of the Alexander horned sphere. How would you "complete" $M$ to a closed manifold $K$? This completion would need to contain the limit point of the 'arms', but that point would have no disk-like (or half-disk-like) neighborhood in $N$.

Comment: can you think of some additional assumption on $M$ to exclude this kind of pathological objects? In particular I'm interested in $M = F(X)$ being the image under a Nash embedding $F$ of a *convex* non-compact bounded Riemannian manifold $(X,g)$. The convexity of $X$ is not preserved by isometries, but there might be a way to consider only a special class of metrics $g$ such that the Nash embedding is "nice enough" and $F(X)$ does not have this kind of pathological behaviour.

Comment: Nope...I got nuttin'. But what you're asking seems like a separate question, so perhaps you should ask that.